# How to Serialise and Deserialise Flink Avro in Java

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to serialise and deserialise avro messages within apache flink Java. I'm also happy to do implement in in Scala.

I have attached my source code below. I hope the comments within the source code makes it clear enough.

```
package com.example;

// import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;
// import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Properties;

public class StreamingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Reading from a json file
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            // This is the path to the Jason file
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/opt/flink/conf/config.json"));

            // creating our json object
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String bootstrapServer = jsonObject.get("bootstrapServers").toString(); // localhost:32310
            String groupId = jsonObject.get("groupId").toString();
            String kafkaInputTopic = jsonObject.get("kafkaInputTopic").toString();
            String kafkaOutputTopic = jsonObject.get("kafkaOutputTopic").toString();
            String windowTimerInSecondsString = jsonObject.get("windowTimerInSeconds").toString();
            String schemaRegistry = jsonObject.get("schemaReg").toString();
            int windowTimerInSeconds = Integer.parseInt(windowTimerInSecondsString);
            String jobName = jsonObject.get("jobName").toString();

            // Creating our data stream
            final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            env.setParallelism(1); // setting the number of Parallelism processes to 1
            env.enableCheckpointing(5000); // setting the checkpoint
            env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);

            // Our Properties for our data consumption
            Properties consumerProperties = new Properties();
            consumerProperties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer);
            consumerProperties.setProperty("group.id", groupId);
            consumerProperties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistry);
            consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
            consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());

            // This is our Flink kafka consumer
            FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(kafkaInputTopic,
                    new SimpleStringSchema(), consumerProperties);

            DataStreamSource<String> consumedKafkaData = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);
            consumedKafkaData.print();


            Properties producer = new Properties();

            producer.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer);
            producer.setProperty("acks", "1");
            producer.setProperty("retries", "10");
            producer.setProperty("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistry);

            producer.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
            producer.setProperty("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName()); // KafkaAvroSerializer
            // Producer
            FlinkKafkaProducer kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer(
                    bootstrapServer,
                    kafkaOutputTopic,
                    new SimpleStringSchema());

            kafkaProducer.setWriteTimestampToKafka(true);
            consumedKafkaData.addSink(kafkaProducer);


            env.execute(jobName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the pom file

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FlinkDeDup</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlinkDeDup</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>
    <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

        <avro.version>1.8.2</avro.version>
        <confluent.version>3.3.1</confluent.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.13.2</version>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

        <!-- Example:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
            <!--            <version>1.8.2</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>-->
<!--        <version>${confluent.version}</version>-->
<!--        &lt;!&ndash;            <version>7.0.1</version>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--for specific record-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                            <createSetters>false</createSetters>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                            <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!--for specific record-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${avro.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>schema</goal>
                                <goal>protocol</goal>
                                <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                                <stringType>String</stringType>
                                <createSetters>false</createSetters>
                                <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                                <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- This profile helps to make things run out of the box in IntelliJ -->
    <!-- Its adds Flink's core classes to the runtime class path. -->
    <!-- Otherwise they are missing in IntelliJ, because the dependency is 'provided' -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>

            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>idea.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>1.13.2</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>1.13.2</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Here is the configuration

{
"bootstrapServers": "192.168.1.100:31957",
"groupId": "myjob",
"kafkaInputTopic": "in",
"kafkaOutputTopic": "out",
"windowTimerInSeconds": "10",
"jobName": "iMonitor-Deduplication-Job-v1",
"schemaReg" : "http://192.168.1.100:32081"
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Avro, then rather than using `SimpleStringSchema`, you should be using either `AvroDeserializationSchema<T>` or `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` in the consumer constructor.

Comment: `
org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().
        parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Car\",\"namespace\":\"com.example\",\"fields\":" +
                "[{\"name\":\"manufacturer\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}" },{\"name\":\"model\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\"," +
                "\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}}],\"version\":\"1\"}");

FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafkaConsumer2 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(kafkaInputTopic,
ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(SCHEMA$), consumerProperties); `

Comment: I tried the following the above.